# Как вывести на странице рубрики подрубрики в виде ссылок

Tags: php, wordpress

нашла код и не знаю как им воспользоваться. Подскажите новичку, где прописывать:

```php
$current_term = get_queried_object();

$terms = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy' => [ 'taxonomy_name' ],
    'parent'         => $current_term->term_id,
] );

var_dump( $terms );
```

Comment: `где прописывать` -- там где хотите вывести. Если тема не кастомная, то сделайте [дочернюю тему](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)